# Update data in MySql javascritpt

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, jsp

I need to update data in my db MySql in javascript. 
I have a function that pass parameter to a servlet but it seems that doesn't work.
Here is my function

```
    function editTable(id,valore){
        var url = "../ModificaPersonaAttivitaServlet?";
        url += "type=perso_atti&value1=" + id+"&value2="+valore;
        xmlhttp4.onreadystatechange = handlerForEdit;
        xmlhttp4.open("GET", url);
        xmlhttp4.send("");

    }
```

Here my handlerForEdit

```
    function handlerForEdit(){

    if (xmlhttp4.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp4.status == 200) {
            var jsonObject = eval('(' + xmlhttp4.responseText + ')');

    }
    }
```

and here is my servlet

```
    package it.timesheet.servlet.ajax;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
    import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
    import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

    import it.timesheet.pojo.PersonaAttività;
    import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
    import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

    /**
     * Servlet implementation class LoadPersonaAttivitàServlet
     */
    @WebServlet("/modificaPersonaAttivitaServlet")
    public class ModificaPersonaAttivitaServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private final String TYPE_OF_REQUEST = "type";

        private final String personaattività_TYPE = "perso_atti";

        private final String SELECT_VALUE_KEY1 = "value1";
        private final String SELECT_VALUE_KEY2 = "value2";

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public ModificaPersonaAttivitaServlet()
        {
            super();
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request,         HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
        {
            String type = request.getParameter(TYPE_OF_REQUEST);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

            if (personaattività_TYPE.equals(type))
            {
                String id = request.getParameter(SELECT_VALUE_KEY1);

                String ore=request.getParameter(SELECT_VALUE_KEY2);
                Connection connection = null;
                try {
                    connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","root","wxkj32skapi");
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try
                {
                    Statement pst2= (Statement) connection.createStatement();
                    String query="UPDATE personaattività SET NumeroOre="+ore+" WHERE ID_personaattività=" + id ;
                    pst2.executeUpdate(query);

                }
                catch (SQLException e)
                {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request,         HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,         HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    }
```

can you help me, please? Thank you so much

Comment: Use browser developer tools Network tab to see what your ajax request is sending and receiving.  There's probably a server error of some kind.

Comment: @James How can I do that?

Comment: I have a tables where you can edit the content of the various checkboxes and at the same time, so, update the db with the new content ...
Help please

Comment: If you can figure out what the error is you're much more likely to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to debug where is the problem. See  status of request in browser console . It will tell you good insights.

Also put the debugger at the entry point of servlet method, it will tell you there is no issue on client but on server side. May be some runtime exception.

Comment: @M Sach

the first alert works;
the second alert ( alert('here');) doesn't work.

function handlerForEdit(){
         alert('i am in handlerForEdit');
         
        if (xmlhttp4.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp4.status == 200) {
         alert('herei');
          var jsonObject = eval('(' + xmlhttp4.responseText + ')');
          alert('Object.keys(jsonObject.values).length values '+Object.keys(jsonObject.values).length);
        }
        }